# Get lightbox 2 working in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, lightbox2

I can't get [lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) to work in Angular 2.  I set it up as described in the documentation, but I always get the error "Uncaught TypeError: this.$lightbox.css(...).fadeIn is not a function".  I can't find any example code getting this working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Angular CLI, do it like you import any other external/jQuery libs.

So:

1. npm install --save lightbox2
2. add styles to angular-cli.json:

   `"styles": [
       "styles.css",
       "../node_modules/lightbox2/dist/css/lightbox.min.css"
   ],`
3. add script to angular-cli.json

   `"scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
       "../node_modules/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.js"
     ],`
4. add the images to your template, e.g (using with semantic ui)

   `<a href="/assets/img/flag.png" data-lightbox="image" data-title="My caption">
       <img class="ui bordered small image" src="/assets/img/flag.png">
   </a>`

Comment: New to Angular, was banging to find angular-cli.json. it is ACTUALLY .angular-cli.json   .    That means there is a DOT at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you, SKumar. This is due to the fact that Angular CLI has renamed their configuration file since the posting of this answer. I will leave it as is.

Comment: Ahh... since I am very new in Angular. I didn't know it was like that earlier... It is very difficult to understand when they(Angular) change things like this in every new version. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

**If you do not want to use jQuery seperately,**

If you do not have `jQuery` support in your project and you do not want to use `jQuery` seperately, you can link to following Lightbox js file, which comes with inbuild `jQuery` support,

```
"scripts": [    
    "../node_modules/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want to used lightbox2 then first install jquery ..

```
cmd:npm install jquery --save
```

after this install ,

```
cmd:npm install lightbox2 --save
```

then add style file in angular.json file

```
"styles": [

          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", // jquery always used before the lightbox2
          "./node_modules/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/lightbox2/dist/css/lightbox.min.css"

        ],
```