# Uncaught TypeError: this.$lightbox.css(...).fadeIn is not a function

Tags: angular, fadein, lightbox2

So i was trying to implement lightbox2 in my Angular 4 App following this 
[Documentation](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started)

First Step

```
npm i --save lightbox2
```

Second Step: Adding the css and js to my .angular-cli.json like so

```
  "styles": [
    ...,
    "../node_modules/lightbox2/dist/css/lightbox.min.css",
    ...
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
    ...
    "../node_modules/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.js"
  ],
```

As you can see, the lightbox.js is listed after the jQuery one.

Third Step
My test images look like this, where each one has it's own unique name as to not to group them together.

```
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/560/560/business/1" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/business/1" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
```

npm start produces no error messages so i imagine i did not mess up the third step. Still, when i click on an image i get directed to a separate tab while chrome logs

> Uncaught TypeError: this.$lightbox.css(...).fadeIn is not a function
>       at b.start (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (VM19984 scripts.bundle.js:60), :12:4058)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (VM19984 scripts.bundle.js:60), :12:987)
>       at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (VM19984 scripts.bundle.js:60), :3:10551)
>       at HTMLBodyElement.q.handle (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (VM19984 scripts.bundle.js:60), :3:8578)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM19983 polyfills.bundle.js:2970)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (VM19983 polyfills.bundle.js:2737)
>       at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (VM19983 polyfills.bundle.js:3044)
>       at invokeTask (VM19983 polyfills.bundle.js:4085)
>       at HTMLBodyElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (VM19983 polyfills.bundle.js:4111)

I did find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119842/get-lightbox-2-working-in-angular-2/42401105#42401105) regarding a similar matter with angular 2 but it did not help me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zahmoulovic's Answer did indeed work and it brought me to look for problems regarding angular-cli and jquery. As it turned out, switching from

```
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
```

to

```
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
```

was all it took.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your **index.html** inside ** head tag**:

```
 <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
```

And delete the jquery.slim.min.js import in angular-cli.json.
Apparently, jquery is not recognised in your angular-cli.json. You have to import the script in index.html.

Tried in a sample project and works only with that import.

**EDIT**

I think **j4g0** solution is a cleaner. It's better to put script and css imports inside angular-cli.json